# Place specific item of Array at the end of it

Tags: php, arrays

I would like select a specific item of a PHP array and place it at the end of the array. My array consist of an unknown number of items (that is, you don't know in advance how many items there will be) and I would like to select the one with key `Other` and place it at the end of the array.

I've tried some with the `array_diff()`, but I couldn't manage to select the `Other` item. I was able to select and unset the item with the `Other`-key in a foreach loop, but couldn't place it at the end of the array. So any advice would be great.

Comment: can you post the sample array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arr = array( 'key' => 'test', 'other' => 'test2', 'key2' => 'test3' );

$arr_other = $arr['other']; 

unset( $arr['other'] );

$arr['other'] = $arr_other;

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: It's that simple and yet I didn't saw it. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = array(
    'one' => 'some value',
    'other' => 'some value',
    'two' => 'some value',
    'three' => 'some value',
);



$other = $array['other'];
unset($array['other']);
$array['other'] = $other;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$tmp = $array['Other'];
unset($array['Other']);
$array['Other'] = $tmp;
```